# Hide container when there is no place

Tags: android, android-layout

Is it possible in a simple way to hide container which is between two other containers in relative layout when there is no enough place to display all images inside it?

Comment: Have you already tried something? Or at least some code we can start with. That makes it easier for us

Comment: I don't think code change anything. I have Relative layout and inside it 3 LinearLayouts and I'm inserting images into container which is in the middle and I want to check if there is enough space to display it. I used set position base on `onLeftOf` and `onRightOf` but it just cut 1 of many images inside container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved it using `getRight()` and `getLeft()` methods by compering each containers position and hide them if necessary.